# Child telling parents about child's difficulties

Tags: kibbud-av-veim-honoring

If a person is having difficulties, what is the correct approach to telling parents?

We don't wish to cause our parents anguish in any way (Kibbud av va'em), so there is a side to say we should avoid telling them unless absolutely necessary. Yet, if they are bound to find out, it will cause them distress if they feel one doesn't feel comfortable coming to them with one's problems.

We also don't want to offend them (Ish imo v'aviv tira'u), so there is a side to say tell them the moment one feels they would have insisted one should tell them (especially if they were going to find out anyway). Yet, there is what to consider about not "bothering" one's venerated parents with one's problems (especially if they have problems of their own).

Some extra thoughts

- a parent will pray for their children with more kavana than anyone else (source - common sense), so the child would benefit from telling them, so that they can pray for them and their situation. They would also be the first to rush to help without any desire for compensation, and would do so with all their strength. Unfortunate exceptions aside of course.
- a child's natural instinct is to "cry for their mother", and a parent's instinct is to protect their child, which might suggest the answer is yes, a child should davka go to their parents when they have problems (everyone is getting what they need). If the halacha is the other way, is it saying anything about these instincts?

Concrete scenarios: Child develops a health concern. Child finds out their town is under threat from a possible enemy attack. Child loses a lot of money. Crime rates go up in the child's area. Child fails an important exam that might mean they fail their course. Child gets arrested.

EDIT: I just saw in "Honouring Parents in Halacha" by Rabbi Tzureil Ta'aseh (Feldheim) pp.67 3:

> Another aspect of honoring one's parents and being in awe of them is
> being very careful not to cause them any distress, whether actively or
> passively. Therefore it is best not to tell them bad news that is not
> important for them to know, even if it does not affect them directly.

Relevant, interesting, although not enough to answer this question.

Comment: It would help if you built a concrete scenario.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi thanks Dr. Please see edit

Comment: Parents can forgo their right to be honored/feared. If a parent wants you to distress them by updating them about your life, that would seem to apply.

Comment: @DoubleAA but what's stopping you from forgoing their forgone and honouring/fearing them anyway

Comment: I doubt you'll get a definitive halachic answer.  Rabbi Chaim Hezekiah Medini, from 19th-century Jerusalem, writes: "No blessing is recited for fulfilling the mitzvah of honoring parents, because you never know if you have fulfilled it properly. [And saying a blessing in vain is prohibited.]"  [Sdei Chemed v6, Berakhot 1:16]

Comment: There may be some cases where keeping them in the dark helps ... but in a *lot* of cases, the truth will come out sooner or later, and in a much worse way.

Comment: You're not supposed to marry someone who will torment your parents. An ultra-Orthodox family had a son go Centrist Orthodox, and was dating a Centrist Orthodox girl. The parents attempted to complain that this was a torment, to see their son dating a college-educated lady who didn't shave her head or keep chalav yisrael! Rabbi Willig told them that what's done is done, the marriage is just forcing them to accept reality -- and this means that *they* are tormenting themselves. So if a kid's going through something rough, it's the situation, not the telling, that can hurt the parents.

Comment: My Rav said in shul this week a story about a sefardi lady who married ashkenazi against her parents' will, and they disowned her, and when they passed away she refused to sit shiva. When her own son became rebellious, they went to Rav Wallerstein, who sent them to his kabbalist Rav in Yerushalayim, who said this is midda k'negged midda and she should go to their grave to beg forgiveness with a minyan, she did and things quickly improved. I think this story contradicts yours, but not sure, maybe it's just the shiva that was the issue?

Comment: normal healthy parents want their children to tell them about their difficulties no matter how painful they may be. One cannot expect to become a parent and have perfect children who will never experience hardship.  Helping your imperfect children is parenting. To see this as the opposite of honoring your parents seems very strange to me

Comment: @Dude I agree. Yet, we still have to pursue the halacha, maybe it says something that's not common sense

Comment: How can there be a tzad to say that doing the opposite of what your parents want is kibbud?

Comment: @Heshy indeed it does sound like a strong contradiction.

Comment: @RabbiKaii See Rama (YD 240:25) who rules a son does not have to obey his parents' wishes when deciding on a marriage partner: "וכן אם האב מוחה בבן לישא איזו אשה שיחפוץ בה הבן – אין צריך לשמוע אל האב (מהרי"ק שורש קס"ז)". The great majority of poskim extend this halacha to a daughter as well (e.g., [*Tzitz Eli'ezer* 13:78](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14512&st=&pgnum=170)).

Comment: @RabbiKaii https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64899